# How to distantly change the another cell text

Tags: google-sheets

I have the drop-down list(l2), which depends on another drop-down list(l1) (like here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4667-google-sheets-dependent-drop-down-list.html). But when I choose another value from l1, the now-invalid value in l2 is labeled as error.

How can I automatically validate the l2 value? Is there any way to distantly change the value of another cell (like "write 'rewrite' function in one cell, and it rewrites the another cell value")?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "But when I choose another value from l1, the now-invalid value in l2 is labeled as error." Yep, that's the thing about **dependant** validation - and no, you can't automatically validate the I2 value, because who knows what value you want it to be. The only solution that I have seen (and it is script-based) is to delete any existing value in I2 when you choose a new value in I1.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks for your answer. Sadly, but I rather prefer to leave it as is, if there is no other solution.

Comment: Sure thing. Just for completeness: what I should have mentioned added is that the entire dependant dropdown was script based. So "deleting any existing value in I2 when you choose a new value in I1" was just one aspect of the script.

Comment: @VladSikorskiy you are going to have to provide me a small sample with what it is doing and what you would like it to do as I can not quite understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CodeCamper Thanks, but help is no longer needed. I already solved my problem thanks to tip from Tedinoz. Script was quite simple, but it works:
`function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.rowStart === 14 && e.range.columnStart === 8) { 
    e.range.offset(0,-4).clearContent();
  }
}`

Comment: @VladSikorskiy I figure out answers to my questions all the time, I suggest you actually post an answer to your own question so that anyone in the future who has this question can see the answer and maybe clarify things a bit. You can also select your own answer as the answer to the question.